# Itextsharp PDFPTable how to make a border around entire table

Tags: c#, itext

I'm building a table via a database in Itextsharp with PDFPTable, and the requirements are that no rows/cells in the table have a top or bottom bottom border, but the left and right sides of each cell have a black border (in other words, each column has a left a right border), and the bottom of the table needs to be closed off with a black border as well, which is where my problem lies.

What I'm doing is setting the border to 0, then manually assign borders so that I only get the left and right borders on each cell, as seen below as an example of a "Quantity" column being generated:

```
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Qty.value, subheaderFont));
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE; 
    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(220, 220, 220);
    cell.Border = 0;
    cell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.BLACK;
    cell.BorderWidthLeft = .5f;
    cell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.BLACK;
    cell.BorderWidthRight = .5f;
    table.AddCell(cell);
```

The issue is obviously I have no way of detecting the last row to add the border-bottom, but I imagine there has to be a way to control the border of the "table" itself, or am I taking the wrong approach to this?

Answer (score 3):

As you found, [`PdfPTable`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPTable.cs) doesn't have borders, probably because PDF's don't have tables in the first place. It probably just made more sense to put the borders on the [`PdfPCell`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPCell.cs) directly (even though PDFs don't support those, either). A table is just a collection of cells, anyway, so let them deal with it.

Anyway, the solution is to set the `TableEvent` on your instance of the `PdfPTable` class. To do this you'll need a custom implementation of the [`IPdfPTableEvent`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/IPdfPTableEvent.cs) interface. The below code should generally do this for you (see the notes at the bottom for "generally")

```
class TopBottomTableBorderMaker : IPdfPTableEvent {
    private BaseColor _borderColor;
    private float _borderWidth;

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a top and bottom border to the table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="borderColor">The color of the border.</param>
    /// <param name="borderWidth">The width of the border</param>
    public TopBottomTableBorderMaker(BaseColor borderColor, float borderWidth ) {
        this._borderColor = borderColor;
        this._borderWidth = borderWidth;
    }
    public void TableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        //widths (should be thought of as x's) is an array of arrays, first index is for each row, second index is for each column
        //The below uses first and last to calculate where each X should start and end
        var firstRowWidths = widths[0];
        var lastRowWidths = widths[widths.Length - 1];

        var firstRowXStart = firstRowWidths[0];
        var firstRowXEnd = firstRowWidths[firstRowWidths.Length - 1] - firstRowXStart;

        var lastRowXStart = lastRowWidths[0];
        var lastRowXEnd = lastRowWidths[lastRowWidths.Length - 1] - lastRowXStart;

        //heights (should be thought of as y's) is the y for each row's top plus one extra for the last row's bottom
        //The below uses first and last to calculate where each Y should start and end
        var firstRowYStart = heights[0];
        var firstRowYEnd = heights[1] - firstRowYStart;

        var lastRowYStart = heights[heights.Length - 1];
        var lastRowYEnd = heights[heights.Length - 2] - lastRowYStart;

        //Where we're going to draw our lines
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];

        //I always try to save the previous state before changinge anything
        canvas.SaveState();

        //Set our line properties
        canvas.SetLineWidth(this._borderWidth);
        canvas.SetColorStroke(this._borderColor);

        //Draw some rectangles
        canvas.Rectangle(
                        firstRowXStart,
                        firstRowYStart,
                        firstRowXEnd,
                        firstRowYEnd
                        );
        //They aren't actually drawn until you stroke them!
        canvas.Stroke();

        canvas.Rectangle(
                        lastRowXStart,
                        lastRowYStart,
                        lastRowXEnd,
                        lastRowYEnd
                        );
        canvas.Stroke();

        //Restore any previous settings
        canvas.RestoreState();

    }
}
```

Using it is very easy, just bind an instance to the property:

```
//Create your name as you normally do
var table = new PdfPTable(3);

//Bind and instance with properties set
table.TableEvent = new TopBottomTableBorderMaker(BaseColor.BLACK, 0.5f);

//The rest is the same
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(i.ToString()));
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(220, 220, 220);
    cell.Border = 0;
    cell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.BLACK;
    cell.BorderWidthLeft = .5f;
    cell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.BLACK;
    cell.BorderWidthRight = .5f;
    table.AddCell(cell);
}
```

Above I said "generally" it should work. If you have table headers and/or footers, however, you're going to need to take those into account, too. This shouldn't be too hard but you'll need to adjust the `y` values accounting for `table.HeaderRows` and `table.FooterRows`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using nested tables

```
'CREATE TWO PDFPTABLES
 Dim tblNested1 As New PdfPTable(1)
 Dim tblNested2 As New PdfPTable(3)

 'CREATE CELLS WITH NO BORDER AND ADD THEM TO TABLE2

 Dim cellNested1 = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("CELL1"))
 cellNested1.Border = 0
 tblNested2.AddCell(cellNested1)
 Dim cellNested2 = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("CELL2"))
 cellNested2.Border = 0
 tblNested2.AddCell(cellNested2)
 Dim cellNested3 = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("CELL3"))
 cellNested3.Border = 0
 tblNested2.AddCell(cellNested3)

 'APPEND TABLE2 TO A CELL WITH DEFAULT BORDER

  Dim cell1 As New PdfPCell
  cell1.AddElement(tblNested2)

  tblNested1.AddCell(cell1)

  document.Add(tblNested1)
```

Comment: Maria's answer is the best for this situation. That being said to Chris Hass' point his solution is better for a large project that needs to be maintained and updated. His solution is a DRY one and that approach is better long term. But if quick and dirty is OK them Maria's approach is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same issue found the following solution.
From "iText In Action Second Edition" 
PdfPCell extends Rectangle, inheriting a plethora of methods to change the way borders are drawn and backgrounds are painted..

The method "DisableBorderSide(int Rectangle)" is how to go about removeing borders with any other sizing involved.

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Some Text", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 13, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
cell.BorderWidth = 1;
cell.DisableBorderSide(Rectangle.TOP_BORDER);
cell.DisableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER);
cell.Padding = 3;
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Rectangular = new Rectangle(56, 621, 540,385);
                Rectangular.BorderWidthLeft = 0.1f;
                Rectangular.BorderWidthRight = 0.1f;
                Rectangular.BorderWidthTop = 0.1f;
                Rectangular.BorderWidthBottom = 0.1f;
                cb.Rectangle(Rectangular);
                cb.Stroke();
```

Comment: This nearly duplicates [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325340/1729265).